# «Аллея памяти воинов Афганистана» — прописные/строчные

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Обратился с просьбой решить проблему ненадлежащего состояния *Аллеи памяти воинов Афганистана*.
Как правильно в этом предложении писать название: что с прописной, а что со строчной буквы?